# Optimizing loop sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check whether an item from a list exists one or more times in a data frame column, and if so, then use some info of that entire row to extract some data.

The data frame has entries like this:

```
df = 

      prefix  value                          binary
---------------------------------------------------
0         30  yes  01010000101000000000000000001101
1         29  yes  01010000101001111110111110101011
2         29  no   10000000010011011011110001111011
```

The current code looks something like this:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
for i, binary in enumerate(list_of_binary_numbers):
    print(f"Executing {i+1}")

    list1_tmp = 0
    list2_tmp = 0
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if binary == row["binary"][0 : len(binary)]:
            if row["value"] == "yes":
                list1_tmp += 2 ** (32 - int(row["prefix"]))
            elif row["value"] == "no":
                list2_tmp += 2 ** (32 - int(row["prefix"]))
    list1.append(list1_tmp)
    list2.append(list2_tmp)
```

So basically `list_of_binary_numbers` is a list with shortened binary numbers, and I need to check whether this shortened part of a full binary number exists in the `df`. That's why I do the `[0 : len(binary)]` so they have the same length.

List looks like this:

```
list_of_binary_numbers =

0                   00000010011010000
1                 0000001001101000100
2            000000100110101000000110
3            000000100110101000000111
4             00000010011010100010000
```

The issue is that the `list_of_binary_numbers` are roughly 150.000 items, and so is the data frame. So each main iteration takes roughly 1 sec to do, hence, this will take forever to complete.

I just can't see any other good way to achieve this, so that's why I am asking for some help.

Comment: Sort "df" by "binary" then you can use "Series.searchsorted" to find the first matching binary (if present) and the remaining binaries consecutively after that. This replaces one linear search with a bisection search.

Comment: Re: looping over iterrows, that is often the slowest approach: https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d

Comment: Can you update a  sample of `list_of_binary_numbers` please?

Comment: I have edited with a list of the binary numbers

Comment: And the thing is I am not even sure I can use `isin` or something like that, since it needs to be the start values that match. So even if the sequence of numbers were to be found in the middle of the full `df["binary"]` sequence, then it would be wrong.

Comment: You are looking to match all pairs of `binary` and `row['binary']`. Try building a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for the `list_of_binary_number` then walk the trie for each `binary` in `df`. That way your are looking at `O(m) + O(n)` steps instead of `O(m*n)`.